# WCF Service loses access to Client Certificate

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl-certificate, windows-server-2012

I am hosting my WCF service by NT Windows Service.

The Windows service runs under a local machine user, which is not included to the Local Machine Administrators Group.

The Wcf Service calls a 3rd Party WCF Service which is using a Client Certificate for the Client Authentication.

The Client Certificate is installed under "Personal" for the "Local Computer".

Additionally I have downloaded "Windows HTTP Services Certificate Configuration Tool" https://download.microsoft.com/download/4/5/b/45bab62d-cdd8-42c7-85d0-0275b96db2c5/winhttpcertcfg.msi and granted the NT Service User access to the Client Certificate

```
WinHttpCertCfg.exe -g -c LOCAL_MACHINE\MY -s "*Cer CN*" -a "*My User*"
```

after service start I can reach the 3rd Party service successfully, but after a couple of hours of work I receive SSL Certificate error, which gets fixed after restarting the Windows Service

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If your service is up and running before, but after a period of time, there will be an occasional failure, indicating that the SSL certificate chain has crashed.
I recommend that you update the Dotnetframework version or the operating system version, because the use of the certificate protocol requires a prerequisite.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls
In addition, it is recommended that you do not use self-signed certificates, and in the certificate store, right click the certificate, All Tasks, manage the private keys menu to add the appropriate user groups.
Feel free to let me know If the problem still exists.